# If my workflow errors out, can I roll it back to before the latest event activity?

Tags: 2010, workflow, disaster-recovery

I would like to be able to recover long-running workflows, analyze the fault and maybe deploy a new package that handles the error gracefully. I can't do it if the workflow just up and dies on me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything that would do this automatically.

You could, however, create a separate column in the list that simply stores status information.  Then, everytime your workflow kicks off, it starts by seeing if you have an existing status in that column and then skips to that step if it was part way through the workflow previously.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I feel that, for large workflows, this would significantly complicate the logic, plus we would have to store the workflow state somewhere, and recreate just the workflow tasks that haven't been completed by that point. I'd like to see if someone found a way to use the default Sharepoint mechanisms for this.

Comment: It doesn't overly complicate things too much, you just have to include additional logic to check that column. If the additional tracking column = x (which would be your previous state) and tracking column equals current state, do x.

Comment: Just add an IF statement on each step before it starts.  Easy enough.

Comment: That would double the amount of work needed to build a workflow :-( I still feel that there should be an easier way, but I'll try your suggestions and see what comes of it.

Comment: Just an idea: In a fault handler for each activity (or group of activities) have a onWorkflowModified event and have a [workflow modification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms480794.aspx) form at hand - so when error occurs, the workflow waits when you initiate "continue" at your workflow modification. Its just an idea and not sure if that would work.